# -Как пользователям запустить одновременно одно и тоже же джава приложение в линукс через x2go?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, сервер, rdp

Дано:

убунту 20, два пользователя, доступ к xfce графическому рабочему столу через x2go (грубо говоря аналог xrdp), установлена джава 17, установлено джава приложение (оно есть прямо в списке в системе, удобно для юзера).

Проблема:

Пользователь запустил джава пприложение и работает с ним. Зашел второй пользователь и тоже хочет работать с этим приложением - получает ошибку, что оно уже запущено. Таким образом два пользователя одновременно не могут исползовать это приложение.

Какие варианты решения задачи без костылей?

Comment: Нужно разобраться, как конкретно приложение определяет, что оно уже запущено, и отталкиваться уже от этого знания

Comment: возможно оно просто видит, что уже есть в памяти. А может в комплекте какой-то скрипт с ним, который это проверяет.

Comment: Может в контейнер ее запаковать попробовать чтобы долго не возиться?

Comment: Оба пользователя логинятся под одним и тем же локальным юзером?